# How to identify the matching field(s) for MongoDB text search?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, database

I set up a compound text index on two fields on my collection. I want to perform a text search on these two fields. Testing it out with the following command gave me satisfactory results.

```
    db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "term"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

However, I would like to know along with each result which of the two indexed fields matched the search term.

Is this possible? It seems so incredibly basic and I can't find support for this feature.

Comment: It might seem basic to you but the feature designers would disagree, as there is no such feature to identify which field in an index contained the match(es) for provided terms. The larger scope is generally a bit to broad but there are basic "hacks". 1. Assign different weights to the fields, where the returned score should give "some" indication of which field was used. 2. Run the text search through `.aggregate()` and project the score, then "attempt" to match the terms. In the latter case there is only limited support for how you can possibly match, and it's generally dependent on your data

Comment: In either case it's all generally academic unless you want to affect the "score" and thus the ranking. In this case Option 1 is the most plausible since if you care which field has the match, then simply apply more "weight" to that field in the index. The broader consideration is "text search" in MongoDB as with most "general" database engines is a "very basic" feature. If you want "more specific features", then you are always better of using a product "dedicated" to text searching instead.