# MongoDB Full text search: Get array name with key where term occurs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search

I have a number of documents with document structure like the following:

```
{
_id:"abcd",
"first_array":[
 {
    "value":["A", "B"], 
    "value":["C", "D"], 
 },
 {
    "value":["A", "C"]
 }
],
"second_array":[
 {
    "value":["P", "Q"], 
    "value":["C", "A"], 
 },
 {
    "value":["R", "S"]
 }    
]
}
```

I want to search these documents and get the array name in which a particular search term has occurred. So when searching for "B" and "P", I need the output in following format(or similar format)

```
{_id:"abcd",{"first_array":  "value":["A", "B"], "second_array": "value":["P", "Q"]} }
```

How should I write my query? TIA.

Comment: Plenty of existing discussion on this. Not possible. First search result that comes up for me. [How to identify the matching field(s) for MongoDB text search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45227276/2313887)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/